# C Using pipes to transfer data to write to file using shared memory

Tags: c, pipe, shared-memory, race-condition

I am trying to use pipes in C. I have two  create two  pipes between parent and child process.I have to read a file in chunks of 4096 bytes (or smaller if there is less) and I have to send through the pipes the amount of data that was read and how many times there have been readings. For example, to copy a 6KB
file, the parent writes the first 4KB data of the file to the shared memory and send two integers, 1 and 4096, to the child via the pipe. The child receives these two numbers, copies 4096 bytes from the shared memory to the output file, and sends back 1 to the parent via the other pipe. After receiving 1,
the parent copies the left 2KB data to the shared memory and send 2 and 2048 to  the child. The child receives them from the pipe, copies 2048 bytes to the output file, and replies with 2 to the parent. The parent then send 0, 0 to the child. The child receives 0 and replies with a 0 and then exit. The parent
receives 0 and exits too.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 4096
#define NUM_OF_PIPES 2
#define P_READ 0
#define P_WRITE 1
#define C_READ 2
#define C_WRITE 3

int main(int argv, char *argc[]) {


  /*Check if program is called correctly*/
  if(argv != 3) {
    printf("Please call program appropriately\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  FILE *r, *w, *check;
  void *sharedMem;
  int pipes[4];
  int shm;
  char userInput[5];
  char *name = "dm11ad_cop4610";
  int inChild = 0;
  int inParent = 0;
  r = fopen(argc[1], "rb");
  check = fopen(argc[2], "rb");

  /*Check if read file can open*/
  if(r == NULL)  {
    perror("Error opening read file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  /*Check if write file can open*/
  if(check == NULL) {
    perror("Error with write file");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else {
    fseek(check, 0, SEEK_END);
    int writeLen = ftell(check);
    if(writeLen > 0) {
      rewind(check);
      printf("Would you like to overwrite file (yes/no): ");
      scanf("%s", userInput);
      if(!strcmp(userInput, "yes")) {
        printf("Overwriting file...\n");
        w = fopen(argc[2], "wb");
      }
      else if(!strcmp(userInput, "no")) {
        printf("Will not overwrite\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
      else {
        printf("User input not accepted\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PIPES; i++) {
    if (pipe(pipes+(i*2)) < 0) {
        perror("Pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
  }

  /*Check if forking process is successful*/
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid < 0) {
    perror("Fork");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  shm = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
  if(shm == -1) {
    perror("Shared memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  if(ftruncate(shm, SIZE) == -1) {
    perror("Shared Memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  sharedMem = mmap(NULL, SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm, 0);
  if(sharedMem == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("Mapping shared memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(pid == 0) {
    while(inParent); 
    inChild = 1; 
    printf("I am in child\n");
    close(pipes[P_READ]);
    close(pipes[P_WRITE]);
    printf("Closed P pipes\n");
    int cBytes, len;
    printf("Im stuck\n");
    len = read(pipes[C_READ], &cBytes, sizeof(cBytes));
    printf("There are %i bytes\n", len);
    if(len < 0) {
      perror("Failed to read from pipe");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if(len == 0) {
      printf("End of fle reached\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Writing to file\n");
        fwrite(sharedMem, 1, sizeof(sharedMem), w);
      }

    printf("Closing C pipes\n");
    close(pipes[C_READ]);
    close(pipes[C_WRITE]);
    printf("Exiting Child\n");
    inChild = 0;
  }
  else {
  while(inChild);
  inParent = 1;
  close(pipes[C_READ]);
  close(pipes[C_WRITE]);
  int pBytes;

  int P2SHM = fread(sharedMem, 1, SIZE, r);
  if(P2SHM < 0) {
    perror("Could not store to shared memory");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if(write(pipes[P_WRITE], &P2SHM, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
    perror("Failed to write to pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int C2P = read(pipes[P_READ], &pBytes, sizeof(int));
  if(C2P < 0) {
    perror("Failed to read value from pipe");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  else if(C2P == 0) {
    printf("End of file reached\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Received succesfully\n");
  }

  close(pipes[P_READ]);
  close(pipes[P_WRITE]);
  inParent = 0;
  printf("Waiting for child\n");
  wait(NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The printfs are  there  to help me see where the program is during execution. It gets stuck in child process, it seems during

```
 len = read(pipes[C_READ], &cBytes, sizeof(cBytes));
```

This is an assignment, so please do not post code as an answer but rather please hep  me understand what I am doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Synchronization mechanism between child and parent looks suspicious:

```
while(inParent); 
inChild = 1;
```

and

```
while(inChild);
inParent = 1;
```

Initial values for `inChild` and `inParent` is `0`. After child process created each process has it's own copy of variable values. When you change `inChild = 1` and `inParent = 1`, it's changed inside the current process only. Other process doesn't see new values and cannot wait for the input/output.

To fix it you should use better synchronization algorithm, e.g. processes semaphores. Read ["5.2 Processes Semaphores"](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch05-ipc.pdf) to get details.

Comment: That does look suspicious, and in fact it is ineffectual.  But the code does not actually rely on it at all.  It is I/O on the pipes that provides synchronization (or is meant to do, anyway).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Right, pipe's synced IO gives a synchronization, but as we can see in code it's not what the author expects.

Comment: I agree that it looks like the OP may have an incorrect expectation there, but none of this has anything to do with the program misbehavior the OP asked about.

Answer (score 1):

> It gets stuck in child process, it seems during
>
> ```
> len = read(pipes[C_READ], &cBytes, sizeof(cBytes));
> ```

Well yes, I imagine it does.

You've been a bit too clever, I think, in setting up a single 4-element array for the pipe-end file descriptors.  That's not inherently wrong, but it tends to obscure what's going on a bit.

Consider what the pipes are supposed to do for you: one process writes to the write end of a pipe, and the other reads what was written from the read end of that same pipe.  Look carefully at which file descriptors each process is reading from and writing to.

Comment: Ok so i re-defined the pipe ends appropriately. Now, when it writes to file, it only writes a small amount of the file. I think this has to do with my 
fwrite(sharedMem, 1, sizeof(sharedMem), w)
but  am unsure.

Comment: @David, that would be a separate question, but you appear to have identified the locus of the problem.  Since `sharedMem` is a `void *`, `sizeof(sharedMem)` evaluates to the size of a `void *`, which has nothing to do with the size of the object, if any, to which the pointer points.  It's probably either 4 or 8 bytes for you.  You cannot measure the size of an allocated object that way.  Indeed, you cannot *measure* the size of a dynamically-allocated object at all.